# Flatten a drop down list in a pdf form

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I have a dropdown list in my pdf form. After filling in the value programmatically, it appears normal.
[image]

But if I flatten the pdf, it looks the following:
Is there anyway to fix this?
[image]

This is my code:

```cs
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(@"mypdf.pdf");
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(@"demo.pdf");

            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter);
            Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);
            PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
            IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();
            PdfFormField toSet;
            fields.TryGetValue("Status of Application", out toSet);
            toSet.SetValue("Applied").SetFontSize(10);

            form.FlattenFields();
            pdfDoc.Close();
            document.Close();
```

Comment: This might be an error in the iText form flattening code. Please supply an example PDF for which the issue occurs for analysis.

Comment: I am wondering is there some ways I can get rid of it? Like changing the field to a text field so that I don't need to fix this issue?

Comment: That may be possible.

Comment: @user16971617 try changing the font of the form field